# Android action icons in actionbar doesn't appear in a MainActivity

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, icons

Icon of about in actionbar doesn't appear in the MainActivity it appear in the overflow menu but in the others Activity it appears without any problems

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/about_app"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/about_app"/>

</menu>
```

But when I change it to this

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/about_app"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_about"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title="@string/about_app"/>

</menu>
```

The icon of about appear in just the MainActivity and in the others Activitys it diseapper and it appear in the overflow menu

Comment: Are you extending all activity with ActionBarActivity?

Comment: Thank you, the problem come from the extends ActionBarActivity in the MainActivity, the others Activity they were working good because I extends Activity, my application have API 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem come from the MainActivity because I extends ActionBarActivity for App who have API 11, to resolve the problem you should extends Activity and use the android:showAsAction and for API 11 or higher  than 11.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Android Support library you should use `app:showAsAction="ifRoom"` (Note the `app:` namespace).

To make an action bar item visible always change `ifRoom` to `always`, otherwise, if the title is long the system will place the item in the overflow menu.

Comment: I'm using android-support-v7-appcompat, i already did it and just like i said  when i use the app:showAsAction the icon appear in the MainActivity and the overflow menu appear in others Activity and if i use the android:showAsAction it appear the overflow menu at the MainActivity and the icon appear in the others Activity

Comment: Great, so now you should change `ifRoom` to `always`

Comment: always the same problem and for information the same title in all the activity